# Dual slope ADC Problem

Tags: adc, integrator

[image]

Here is my try at the problem,

A 3.5 digit implies the count varies from 0 to 1999.So for a 2V full scale the LSB or the resolution is 1mV.

Now the input is integrated for 300ms and the integrated value is 0.30114V, which is now de- integrated down while counter starts to count simultaneously i suppose.
Thus the counter should count till : (assuming reference voltage of 0V)
0.30114 / 1mV = 301 (digital output).

MY doubt:
Is my approach correct ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what is meant by "1sin314t" maybe you might want to clear that up.

Comment: just a clamped sinusoid of 50Hz which varies from 0 to 2 about 1V dc.

Comment: Hint: Consider the sum rule of integration and that 300ms is 15 complete 50Hz cycles.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  so the sine averages out to zero and only 1V to be considered huh ? In which case the output doesn't change much , the integral of 1 over 300ms is still 0.3 which gives 300 as digital output.am I right ?

Comment: No, but @DaveTweed has given you the answer for your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not correct.

The integration time and the clock rate of the counter are related such that a full-scale input (1.999V) gives 1999 counts. From this, you can infer that the clock speed is 2000 counts/300 ms = 6667 Hz (not the 2000 Hz that you seem to be assuming).

Therefore, a half-scale input will give half the count in the counter, or 1000 counts.

The only reason the integration time was given was so that you would realize that it incorporates only whole cycles of the AC frequency, and since the mean value of a sine wave is zero, it contributes nothing to the final reading.

Integration times that are multiples of 100 ms are commonly used in digital multimeters, because this gives good rejection of both 50 Hz and 60 Hz interference.